# Tortoise Hg merge shows file in merge but THG COMMIT shows no changes

Tags: merge, output, tortoisehg

There are times when executing merges between branches that the tortoise hg commit window will show a file as part of the merge results and that it is about to be commited; however there are times when in the diff window it shows absolutely nothing about the file.

Going to the command line and running `hg log -l 1 --patch` shows that the file is indeed different.

Does anyone have any explanation to why this occurs? Is there a legitimate reason as to why THG feels it does not need to display these changes in the diff window?

(in case it matters, THG version 2.5.1, with Mercurial-2.3.2, Python-2.7.3, PyQt-4.9.1, Qt-4.8.0)

Comment: Did you check if file's encoding is different. For example ascii vs utf-8. TortoiseHg shows that files are different but diff shows nothing.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur but the patch output would contain the differences regardless?

Comment: No, since this is binary difference only. Patch output contains only text difference.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, I think you should report it. https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/new

Comment: @ErikB this behavior has existed for numerous years across numerous versions, i always assume it was expected (and i just don't know why it was expected) as it seems to be a rather critical issue if it was a bug that has been flatly ignored.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Well, if it is expected they will close the bug as by design and hopefully give you an explanation to why it is like this, which will answer your question.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/3469/merge-commits-do-not-show-changes-to-files